# MongoDB: Replacement for MongoDB::execute to call JS function on server

Tags: php, mongodb

I recently found out that the `MongoDB::execute` method was deprecated on the PHP MongoDB extension:

> MongoDB::execute — Runs JavaScript code on the database server
>   [deprecated]

I was using this method to call some javascript functions already stored on the server, as follows:

```php
$result= $db->execute("myTestFunction()");
print $result["retval"];
```

**Now that `MongoDB::execute` no longer works, how can I call a JS function on the server?** I've tried the `::command` method in a bunch of ways and I get `no such command: 'myTestFunction'`.

My goal is to run heavy operations (that manipulate a lot of data) on the database itself avoiding having to pull the data into PHP and sending it back to other collections. In case it no longer possible to call JS functions from PHP what's the best practice here?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what `myTestFunction()` is meant to be doing if you want advice on what to do instead. The reality here is that JavaScript on the server was really only ever a "band aid" for other things that were not yet implemented at the time of the initial release of MongoDB. Gradually those JavaScript engine features are being removed, and will continue to do so

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you for the answer, it is a clean up operation where documents marked for deletion are anonymized (removed any user info) and copied for another collection for later usage in metrics.

Comment: I mean a **specific explanation** rather than a general statement that is already within your question. Currently you are not really asking a question. All you are saying is *"MongoDB won't let me run my JavaScript function, so how do I run my JavaScript function"*. The only answer is **you don't**. But if you want to know what to do ( **not JavaScript** ) instead, then **describe the process** as your question instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn Specific reason? The collection has around 500 MB of data / day to anonymize, process and store in another collection. Pulling all this data to PHP, manipulating it and then sending it back takes a long time. Running all this directly inside a DB javascript function was way faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an alternative. Mongodb has deperacted eval and will not be continuing support for the eval feature in the future. You have to work without it in the future